# Facebook share through my website and get likes and shares count only?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a website where it would be crucial to be able to view the likes and shares of a specific post a user shares from the website.. Is this possible anymore? The flow would be similar to this:

User logs in through Facebook and grants user_posts permission
User then clicks a share button for a specific url with quote content and a hashtag

What I need after those steps are:
ID of the post from sharing
Count of likes, reactions and shares on that post

even better would be a webhook notice of likes/reactions/shares count.

Any ideas? I don't need any private data... just counts of likes/reactions/shares but it's not looking possible anymore.

Comment: what for exactly? what would you do with the data? i need to ask, because the answer kind of depends on that question.

Comment: I need the data to determine how much a person has helped a cause they're sharing. Like spreading the word on Red Cross.

Comment: What would you need that information for?

Comment: Can't say exactly why but it tracks social impact for causes.

Comment: we still don´t know exactly how you want to use the information, and that´s a very important question.

Comment: A user signs up on my site, makes a pledge and fulfills it based on the number of shares and likes received on their post. So it would display on my website how many likes and shares they received through post(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.4

> Don't incentivize people to post content on Facebook, or give the
>   impression that posting to Facebook will be rewarded

Incentivizing users for posting/sharing something on their personal wall is not allowed, you would not get the `user_posts` permission approved for that, and that makes it impossible.